# How can I forward an email while preserving metadata without resending the email to CC recipients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, email-forwarding

Let's say I set up email forwarding on my gmail (e.g. fabian@gmail.com -> fabian@hmail.com).

sender@domain.com sends an email to fabian@gmail.com and cc spy@domain.com. I receive a copy of the email at fabian@gmail.com and fabian@hmail.com, but spy@domain.com only receives one copy. The forwarding of the email doesn't result in an additional email being sent to spy@domain.com.

But more importantly, fabian@hmail.com receives the email with spy@domain.com in the CC list (metadata is preserved).

I tried to set up an email forwarding service on AWS by creating a new email and copying over the headers. E.g. alias@forwarding.com receives an email and changes the "to" header to fabian@gmail.com. For all other headers (including the cc header), it copies it over. However, if I do that, CC recipients receive another email sent from Amazon.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Did a write-up here: https://medium.com/@fabianterh/diving-deep-into-emails-smtp-envelopes-and-headers-a2367d1ad92